# Pytorch: Illegal instruction core dumped when loading ResNet50 model

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch, resnet

I'm new to pytorch and I'm using ResNet50 model to train.

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)

for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False

model.fc = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(2048, 512),nn.ReLU(),nn.Dropout(0.2),nn.Linear(512, 10),nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1))
criterion = nn.NLLLoss()

optimizer = optim.Adam(model.fc.parameters(), lr=0.003)
model.to(device)


epochs = 1
steps = 0
running_loss = 0
print_every = 10
train_losses, test_losses = [], []
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for inputs, labels in trainloader:
        steps += 1
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        logps = model.forward(inputs)
        loss = criterion(logps, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss += loss.item()

        if steps % print_every == 0:
            test_loss = 0
            accuracy = 0
            model.eval()
            with torch.no_grad():
                for inputs, labels in testloader:
                    inputs, labels = inputs.to(device),labels.to(device)
                    logps = model.forward(inputs)
                    batch_loss = criterion(logps, labels)
                    test_loss += batch_loss.item()

                    ps = torch.exp(logps)
                    top_p, top_class = ps.topk(1, dim=1)
                    equals = top_class == labels.view(*top_class.shape)
                    accuracy += torch.mean(equals.type(torch.FloatTensor)).item()
            train_losses.append(running_loss/len(trainloader))
            test_losses.append(test_loss/len(testloader))                    
            print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{epochs}.. "
                  f"Train loss: {running_loss/print_every:.3f}.. "
                  f"Test loss: {test_loss/len(testloader):.3f}.. "
                  f"Test accuracy: {accuracy/len(testloader):.3f}")
            running_loss = 0
            model.train()
```

This code works fine in Google Colaboratory but in my local machine(CPU), on execution of "model.forward(inputs)", it gives an error "Illegal instruction core dumped". I've tried updating my pytorch version, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

please try with: CPU:#-GPU (e.g.:0)

### example

```
import torch
import torch
import pycuda.driver as cuda
cuda.init()
torch.cuda.is_available()
# True
## Get Id of default device
torch.cuda.current_device()
# 0
cuda.Device(0).name() # '0' is the id of your GPU
# Tesla K80
```

---

source: full ref at
https://medium.com/p/speed-up-your-algorithms-part-1-pytorch-56d8a4ae7051

Comment: I am working my way through the very first PyTorch tutorial on a machine with no GPU, and get the same error. Isn't it possible to run PyTorch without GPU support?